# What inspired Shekondar?

Tags: neal-stephenson

**Shekondar** is a name that shows up across several unrelated Neal Stephenson books, always referring to something different.

In *The Big U*:

> Tonight they were testing Shekondar Mark V, their state-of-the-art
> Sewers & Serpents simulation program.

In *Cryptonomicon*:

> But Randy does find one [CD] from an evidently Seattle-based band
> called Shekondar.... Now, Shekondar happens to have been the name of
> an especially foul underworld deity who played an important role in
> some of the game scenarios that Randy played with Avi and Chester and
> the gang back in the old days.

In *REAMDE*:

> Steadying himself on an eight-foot wizard's staff as he waded through
> a knee-high river of blood washing down the market street of Bagpipe
> Gulch - a community that once prized its status as the "Gateway to
> Torgai" - Shekondar the Fearsome, a local alchemist, ...

What is the Root Rep of Shekondar?  Can its inspiration be tied to any real-world entity or reference?  Has Stephenson ever commented on the inspiration of this name he's reused?

Comment: Just pointing out that _The Big U_ is Stephenson's first published fiction, so in the absence of an interview or something else about Stephenson's life, that'll have to be the answer.